# Unable to bypass basic authentication for a particular URL in Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb, nginx-location

I have read and tried almost all the steps/ options mentioned on the similar posts.
This is how my Nginx file looks like:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass    http://localhost:8000;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
```

I am trying to exclude the following part from basic authentication:

> /engine/v1/status

I have tried the following so far:

```
location **/engine/v1/status** {
            **auth_basic "off"**;
            allow all; # Allow all to see content 

}

location **= /engine/v1/status** {
            **auth_basic off;**
            allow all; # Allow all to see content 

}

location **= /engine/v1/status** {
            **auth_basic "off";**
            allow all; # Allow all to see content 

}
```

I still get an

> HTTP 401: Unauthorized You configured a listener rule to authenticate
>   users. Either you configured OnUnauthenticatedRequest to deny
>   unauthenticated users or the IdP denied access

on my AWS target group
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I presume that the `**`s are just noise. The `off` is a keyword not a string, so should not be quoted. If the location is intended to reverse proxy upstream, it will need a `proxy_pass` statement too.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you for the suggestion. I was able to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to do it.

```
location = /engine/v1/status {
                proxy_pass    http://localhost:8000;
                auth_basic off;
                allow all; # Allow all to see content      
        }
```